# Why isn't ccache used with gcc more often?

Tags: c++, ccache

I've been wondering...

Are there some limitations with ccache?

If the difference in later compile times are so large,
why aren't more Linux developers using ccache more often?

Comment: References for ccache, your information about how many developers use it, and these compile time figures?

Comment: @Useless: Some high level info: *ccache* is a tool that is used as a compiler wrapper, it calls the compiler with the given arguments and caches the result of compilation. If the object file is removed and a new compilation is triggered, *ccache* will check the source file and compiler options and pull the result from the cache if available. Basically it allows for 'make clean; make' with the efficiency of just 'make' (mainly useful if the makefile dependencies are not correctly tracked). [There are details missing as to how to determine whether the cached .o can be used or not]

Comment: So it's a sticking plaster for people who can't write correct makefiles? If you always have to `make clean`, the build system isn't doing its job.

Comment: @Useless: There are other use cases, for example in build farms you may want to force cleaning before build, if correctly configured the cached objects (and output from the compiler I failed to mention that) can be shared in different code paths, allowing parallel work in different directories and `ccache` producing the .o for shared unmodified files... Also note that it is not *that* simple to perfectly track the dependencies for large enough projects that are not built in one step (i.e. a header in a library outside of your current project changes)

Comment: Thy're probably running their builds on the same box they use for WOW/CoD etc. They have RAID-SSDs, 16G of RAM and 8-core watercooled i7's.  If a full build takes 12 seconds, not much point in speeding it up <g>

Comment: @MartinJames: So all of them have my exact setup? Darn, I thought I was unique!

Comment: This all makes sense now that I understand how ccache works. This sounds useless on a developers machine then. I'll just have to wait for C++ modules in the next C++ revision (whenever that is).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess that the simple answer is that `ccache` is great when the build system is broken (i.e. the dependencies are not correctly tracked, and to get everything built correctly you might need `make clean; make`). On the other hand, if dependencies are correctly tracked, then `ccache` will not yield any advantage over plain `make`, and will actually incur the cost of maintaining the cache and updating it (the size of the cache might be *huge* depending on the size of the project)

Comment: +1: write correct, non-recursive makefiles and watch those concurrent builds fly

Comment: ccache is also very helpful when you change something in a widely-included header and then change it back. (Or, say, if all you did was fix a spelling error in a comment in such a header.)

Comment: A build system I use trips up when I switch branches, and ccache really helps with that.

Comment: `ccache` is invaluable if you jump back and forth a lot in the history of a large project, like Chromium. Or if you keep multiple checkouts. Or if you're the one who's got to diagnose and fix those incorrect makefiles.